# LINQ .Select() Accessing parent properties?

Tags: linq, select

I didn't know how to phrase the title of this post.  This is what I am trying to do:

```
invalidItems.AddRange(documents.SelectMany(doc => doc.Messages)
            .Select(message => string.Format("Doc. Key {0}: {1}", doc.ID, message)));
```

Where invalidItems is a List and Document is a class that contains a List property called messages.

I want to get a flat list of the messages (strings) for all of the documents, where the strings are formatted to include the Document ID (similar to the String.Format() above).  Is there a way to accomplish this?

When I working with the message parameter in the final .Select() clause, I am unable to access anything on the parent Document...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the select clause into your SelectMany clause like this:

```
documents.SelectMany(
    doc => doc.Messages.Select(
        message => string.Format("Doc. Key {0}: {1}", doc.ID, message)
    )
);
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks for the speedy reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more scope in your queries, query comprehension syntax may be the way to go.

```
from doc in documents
from message in doc.Messages
select string.Format("Doc. Key {0}: {1}", doc.ID, message)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
documents
.SelectMany(
  doc => doc.Messages,
  (doc, message) => new {doc, message}
)
.Select(
  x => string.Format("Doc. Key {0}: {1}", x.doc.ID, x.message)
)
```

Comment: Nice, that totally works, too.  And I prefer the query expression syntax.